# Unable to access Azure Table Storage through Account Level SAS token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Storage Account and I have created an SAS token for it using the following screen.

[image]

I have an application server with no internet access and a proxy server which is used to access Azure. So while generating the SAS token I am giving an IP address of the Proxy Server.

I have developed a c# program which reads the SAS token and creates a dummy table in Azure Storage Account.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var storageAccount = new StorageAccount();

        //Configure Storage Account and get the reference of a newly created table
        try
        {
            var cloudTableReference = storageAccount.CloudTableInstance;

            if (cloudTableReference != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Table {0} created successfully using SAS token", cloudTableReference.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is an error in new table creation");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in configuring Azure Storage Account - {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But when running from an application server I am always getting an error saying **Error in configuring Azure Storage Account - Configuration system failed to initialize**

**Updated Code**

```
class StorageAccount
{

    private CloudTableClient CloudTableClient { get; set; }

    private CloudTable CloudTable { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fetches Storage Account connection string from App.Config and returns a CloudTableClient object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>CloudTableClient</returns>
    public CloudTableClient ConfigureStorageAccount()
    {
        var storageCred = new StorageCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SASToken"]);

        CloudTableClient = new CloudTableClient(
                        new StorageUri(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountUri"])), storageCred);
        return CloudTableClient;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a CloudTable instance for a Table
    /// </summary>
    public CloudTable CloudTableInstance
    {
        get
        {
            ConfigureStorageAccount();
            CloudTable = CloudTableClient.GetTableReference("TableName");
            CloudTable.Create();
            return CloudTable;
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
<!--PROD Connection Strings-->
<add key="SASToken" value="token"/>
<add key="StorageAccountUri" value="https://ac_name.table.core.windows.net"/>
</appSettings>
<defaultProxy>
<proxy proxyaddress="http://IpPAddrr"/>
</defaultProxy>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with SAS. Can you share the code for `storageAccount.CloudTableInstance`?

Comment: Updated the code. So you think I am creating SAS correctly?

Comment: Yep. SAS looks OK to me. Can you check the inner exception? It looks like there's an issue with your app.config file. Also, please share what is the value for "StorageAccountUri". Is it "https://youraccountname.table.core.windows.net"?

Comment: I have added ```app.config``` file. The inner exception says ```"Unrecognized configuration section defaultProxy."```

Comment: Try to put `<defaultProxy>` settings under `<system.net>` element. So it would be `<system.net><defaultProxy><proxy proxyaddress="http://IpPAddrr"/></defaultProxy></system.net>`. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx.